# How to use Django ImageField to upload to Google Cloud Storage instead of local

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, google-cloud-platform, django-models

I want to use Django's ImageField on a model so people can upload a logo. I found the ImageField however reading from the docs it says `Django stores files locally, using the` **[`MEDIA`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#std-setting-MEDIA_ROOT)*[`ROOT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#std-setting-MEDIA_ROOT)****`and`**[`MEDIAURL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#std-setting-MEDIA_URL)** `settings.py`

I'm wondering how I can change the *`upload_to=` behavior to upload to a gcp bucket instead? If it's possible when I call .`save` what is saved to the database, the gcp bucket url?

From reading the docs it doesn't say one way or the other if this is possible or if all images should be stored locally where the service is being ran. I have thought of saving the binary images directly to the db but that seems inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `django-storages` and `google-cloud-storage`. Here is the document link: [Google Cloud Storage](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/gcloud.html)

> Set the default storage and bucket name in your settings.py file
>
> ## django < 4.2
>
> `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage'`
>
> ## django >= 4.2
>
> `STORAGES = {"default": {"BACKEND": "storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage"}}`

> GS_BUCKET_NAME = 'YOUR_BUCKET_NAME_GOES_HERE'
> To allow django-admin collectstatic to automatically put your static files in > your bucket set the following in your settings.py:

> ## django < 4.2
>
> `STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage'`

> ## django >= 4.2
>
> `STORAGES = {"staticfiles": {"BACKEND": "storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage"}}`

Usage
Fields
Once you’re done, default_storage will be Google Cloud Storage

```
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage
print(default_storage.__class__)
<class 'storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage'>
# This way, if you define a new FileField, it will use the Google Cloud Storage

>>> from django.db import models
>>> class Resume(models.Model):
...     pdf = models.FileField(upload_to='pdfs')
...     photos = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos')
...
```