# Uploading large file to GCS with django and django-storages -- direct or multi-part uploads?

Tags: django, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, python-django-storages

I'm creating a django application that uploads multimedia to Google Cloud Storage using django-storages.  My application is running on Google App Engine; I'm using the admin interface for admins to upload new media.

Right now I'm having trouble with models that contain a large number of images -- for example, some of my models contain several 4K images, and at 25MB/ea I'm easily hitting hundreds of MB per save operation.

`django-storages` is working great for smaller operations, but larger operations are causing issues.  I'm currently getting an HTTP 413 error on larger save operations -- my app is POSTing about 100 MB, and Google App Engine's limit is 32MB.

So my question is: to get around the limit, is it possible to make multiple POST requests using `django-storages`?  Like, if my model has 4x 4K images, can I upload them each in a sequential upload?

I've also read that I should upload files "directly" to GCS -- is it possible to do a "direct" upload using django?  How would I go about doing that?

And either way, I'd have to change how the admin interface uploads file... how can I go about doing that?

thanks!

Comment: Hi, I think that setting `GS_BLOB_CHUNK_SIZE` option to something like 16KB should help. By default `django-storages` trying to load entire uploadable file in memory.

Comment: Can you have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76577680/18265570) & [this document](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/gcloud.html) for uploading files to `cloud storage` from `django`.

Comment: @IlyaKhrustalev by changing the `GS_BLOB_CHUNK_SIZE` will this result in multiple post requests?  The core issue I'm still running into is that Google App Engine only allows 32MB per POST.

Comment: @RoopaM I am currently using `django-storages` as suggested but these posts do not provide any guidance on posting files larger than Google App Engine's 32MB limit

Comment: You can try uploading to `GCS` using [`signed URLs with resumable upload`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls#signing-resumable) or you try using [`Blobstore API`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/blobstore)`.`

Comment: @nathanlachenmyer Have you managed to try above documents?